# Android camera2 face detection

Tags: android, android-camera, face-recognition, face-detection, android-camera2

There is not enough info about camera2 face detection mechanism. I used the Camera2 sample from Google: https://github.com/android/camera-samples

I set face detection mode to FULL.

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                                    CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
```

Also, I checked

`STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT` and `STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES`:

```
int max_count = characteristics.get(
CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT);
int modes [] = characteristics.get(
CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES);
```

**Output**: *maxCount : 5 , modes : [0, 2]*

My CaptureCallback:

```
 private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
 = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
                Integer mode = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE);
                Face [] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
                if(faces != null && mode != null)
                    Log.e("tag", "faces : " + faces.length + " , mode : " + mode ); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                    CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                   TotalCaptureResult result) {
        process(result);
    }
```

**Output**: *faces : 0 , mode : 2*

```
 public static final int STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL = 2;
```

Faces length is constantly 0. Looks like it doesn't detect a face properly or I missed something.

I know the approach with [FaceDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html). I just wanted to check how it works with the new camera2 [Face](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/Face.html).

Comment: [https://github.com/rajktariya/Android-Camera2-Front-with-Face-Detection](https://github.com/rajktariya/Android-Camera2-Front-with-Face-Detection) found this working sample for both front camera with face detection

Answer (score 1):

You can check the ML-KIT from Google:

[Detect faces with ML Kit on Android](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android?hl=en)

And there is a related sample app:
[vision-quickstart](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart)

or if you are using the camera2 there is a working example:
[Camera2Vision](https://github.com/EzequielAdrianM/Camera2Vision)

Answer (score 0):

My attempts were on android 5.0(API 21). After update to 5.1(API 22) it started working without code changes.

Comment: Sorry i have the same problem... But it doesn't solve way like you help... If you manege this problem, can you give a link on github or other resourse? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think your phone is not working good with the Google Face detection. Are you sure that it use HAL3 and can use API2?.

For example, in my code I'm using face detection without any problem like this:

```
 private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mPhotoCaptureCallback
            = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
//more code...
  private void process(CaptureResult result) {
            switch (mState) {
                case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                    checkFaces(result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES));
                   //more code....
                    break;
                }
//more code...
}
```

Here is the checkFaces method:

```
 private void checkFaces(Face[] faces) {
    if (faces != null) {
        CameraUtil.CustomFace[] mMappedCustomFaces;
        mMappedCustomFaces = computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates(faces);
        if (faces != null && faces.length > 0) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_FACES_MSG);
            mLastTimeRenderingFaces = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    } else {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > (mLastTimeRenderingFaces + 100)) {
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(HIDE_FACES_MSG);
        }
    }
}
```

my custom Face class:

```
     //    public static class CustomFace extends Camera.CustomFace{
public static class CustomFace {
    private int score = 0;
    private Rect rect = null;

    public CustomFace(Rect rect, int score) {
        this.score = score;
        this.rect = rect;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public Rect getBounds() {
        return rect;
    }
}
```

finally with this method you can draw the faces correctly(you can use the default android one, but rectangles doesn't work so good in 4:3 or 16:9 sizes or when you rotate the phone:

```
  public static RectF rectToRectF(Rect r) {
    return new RectF(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
}

     private CameraFaceUtil.CustomFace[] computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates(Face[] faces) {
        CameraFaceUtil.CustomFace[] mappedFacesList = new CameraFaceUtil.CustomFace[faces.length];

        mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

        float toStandardAspectRatio = ((float) mPreviewRect.bottom / (float) mPreviewRect.right) / AutoFitTextureView.RATIO_STANDARD;
//
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {

            RectF mappedRect = new RectF();
            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] toStandardAspectRatio: " + toStandardAspectRatio);
            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] preview rect: " + mPreviewRect);
            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] raw rect: " + faces[i].getBounds());

            mCameraToPreviewMatrix.mapRect(mappedRect, CameraUtil.rectToRectF(faces[i].getBounds()));

            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] mapped rect: " + mappedRect);

            Rect auxRect = new Rect(CameraUtil.rectFToRect(mappedRect));


            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] aux rect: " + auxRect);

            int cameraSensorOrientation = mCameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] cameraSensorOrientation: " + cameraSensorOrientation);
            switch (cameraSensorOrientation) {
                case 90:
                    mappedRect.top = auxRect.left;
                    mappedRect.bottom = auxRect.right;
                    mappedRect.left = (mPreviewRect.right - auxRect.bottom);
                    mappedRect.right = (mPreviewRect.right - auxRect.top);
                    break;

                case 180:
                    mappedRect.top = (mPreviewRect.bottom - auxRect.bottom) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    mappedRect.bottom = (mPreviewRect.bottom - auxRect.top) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    mappedRect.left = (mPreviewRect.right - auxRect.right) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    mappedRect.right = (mPreviewRect.right - auxRect.left) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    break;

                case 270:
                    mappedRect.top = (mPreviewRect.bottom - auxRect.right) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    mappedRect.bottom = (mPreviewRect.bottom - auxRect.left) * toStandardAspectRatio;
                    mappedRect.left = auxRect.top;
                    mappedRect.right = auxRect.bottom;
                    break;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] rotated by camera driver orientation rect without scale: "
                    + mappedRect + ",  with score: " + faces[i].getScore());

            float topOffset = mappedRect.top;
            float leftOffset = mappedRect.left;

            mappedRect.top = mappedRect.top * toStandardAspectRatio;
            mappedRect.bottom = mappedRect.bottom * toStandardAspectRatio;
            mappedRect.left = mappedRect.left * toStandardAspectRatio;
            mappedRect.right = mappedRect.right * toStandardAspectRatio;


            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] rotated by camera driver orientation rect with scale: "
                    + mappedRect + ",  with score: " + faces[i].getScore());

            topOffset = mappedRect.top - topOffset;
            leftOffset = mappedRect.left - leftOffset;

            mappedRect.top -= topOffset /*- (mMirror ? mPreviewRect.height() : 0)*/;
            mappedRect.bottom -= topOffset /* - (mMirror ? mPreviewRect.height() : 0)*/;
            mappedRect.left -= leftOffset;
            mappedRect.right -= leftOffset;

            Log.i(TAG, "[computeFacesFromCameraCoordinates] rotated by camera driver orientation rect with offset: "
                    + mappedRect + " topOffset " + topOffset + " leftOffset " + leftOffset);

            // set the new values to the mapping array to get rendered
            mappedFacesList[i] = new CameraFaceUtil.CustomFace(CameraUtil.rectFToRect(mappedRect), faces[i].getScore());
        }

        return mappedFacesList;

    }
```

What I'm doing is drawing the faces based in the screen ratio and size. Feel free to ask if you need something else about camera2API.

Comment: I am doing an experiment on Camera2 Face detection to detect Face landmark using Tflite Model. Can you help me on this?

Comment: @Francisco Durdin Garcia .. I struck to draw the rectangles on exact location on 4:3, 16:9 screens..for front and back cameras...  For front camera the rectangles on the face is show relatively but not in exact location on the face.. please share me the sample code for this calculation

Answer (score 0):

I found that only in case `STATE_PREVIEW`, you can process the result to show faces lenth. [Change from](https://github.com/rajktariya/Android-Camera2-Front-with-Face-Detection/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L287-L301)

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        Integer mode = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE);
        Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
        if(faces != null && mode != null) {
            Log.e("tag", "faces : " + faces.length + " , mode : " + mode);
        }

        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
                break;
            }
...
```

to

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

    private void process(CaptureResult result) {


        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
              Face[] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
              if (faces != null && faces.length > 0) {
                  Log.e("tag", "faces : " + faces.length);
              }
                break;
            }
```

Please try this to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your phone is on API level 21?  [STATISTICS_FACES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult#STATISTICS_FACES) was not added until this API, and earlier phones used separate fields.

You should try running `dumpsys`.  It provides a lot of information including the latest CaptureResult in its complete state.  I like to pipe to grep to search for the 'face' string:

```
adb shell dumpsys media.camera | grep 'face' -A1
```