# How can I detect face properly using Camera2 in Android?

Tags: android, face-detection, camera2

I'm currently using `android.hardware.camera2` module to detect a face.

I revise my own code withe the reference

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic

and

[Android camera2 face recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334319/android-camera2-face-recognition)

However, I had the same problem as the link above. In my case, when I run the code with Galaxy S4, android 5.0 it seems to work properly (Face detection works properly) but when I run the same code with Galaxy S6, android 5.1, faces are not recognized as above link said.

How can I solve this problem? or, Is there a simple tutorial concerning face detection with camera2?

Comment: You might try the new face detection API that is included with Google Play Services.  There are a few tutorials here:  https://developers.google.com/vision/

Comment: Thx @pm0733464 ! finally I could manage the problem with your advice

Comment: Sorry i have the same problem... But it doesn't solve way like you help... If you manege this problem, can you give a link on github or other resourse? Thanks very much!

Comment: Try this. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker I achieve breakthrough with this sample