# How many devices in percent doesn't support face detection feature?

Tags: android, face-detection, android-camera2

In my application, I use OpenCV for face detection throw ImageReader and jni.
It works ok, but performance of that solution isn't so good as I wanted, also I want to reduce size of my app.
I read some information about face detection in camera 2 API, and I have some questions about it.

1) Why the function below can return `STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_OFF`?
Not all devices support face detection feature? What type of devices doesn't support it and why? Do you know any examples of unsupported devices? In my project, I use only front facing camera, does it matter to me?

```
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES);
```

2) What about performance? Is there any performance difference between `STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL` and `STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_SIMPLE`?

Comment: In my experience, the built-in camera2 face detection is not a match to OpenCV. But maybe, on latest devices with extra AI capabilities, its results are more reliable. At any rate, it is much faster than OpenCV.

Comment: You might find some more hints in this discussion: *[Android camera2 face recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334319/android-camera2-face-recognition)*